# Image cache doesn't generate images using nginx

Tags: 8, media

So I'm trying to set up thumbnails for articles written in drupal 8. The thumbnails won't generate though. so I just have 404 image errors.

```
/dl/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/Regular_Photo/xwing_0.jpg?itok=KE4FXSCU
```

I have this in my nginx set up

```
 location @drupal {
    # Allow CORS for ooyala.com
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
            rewrite ^/(\w*)/(.*)$ /$1/index.php?q=$2 last;
    }
    # Caching entry for filetypes
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # CGI for /dl/
    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
            #set $php_root /mnt/nfs_data/RebelFleet/app;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

    # Assist with CSS styles issues
    location ~ ^/dl/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }
location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

    # Assist with CSS styles issues
    location ~ ^/dl/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
             try_files $uri $uri/ @drupal; 
    }
```

At the moment, it doesn't create any thumbnails and not sure why it's not working. I don't get any errors in any logs.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue, how we can fix this?

Comment: tweaking this did it for me I think.

   location ~* ^(?!/system/files).*\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|ttf|svg)$ {
    ## If the image does not exist, maybe it must be generated by drupal (imagecache)
    try_files $uri @drupal;
    expires 7d;
    log_not_found off;
  }